# How to get Timer (Util or Swing) to allow me to call a method in a Netbeans Desktop Application Program?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jsr296

(full source code at the bottom)

So for a quite of bit of time now I have been working on this. I have an ultimate goal, but for the sake of learning how to do this I have created an application that simply adds 1 to a number and displays that as `jLabel1` every second. My problem is I can not get the `Timer` to work.

my research has shown me different ways, and examples of `Timer` functions using the package `java.util.timer` and `javax.swing.timer`. To date none of them have worked. It was never a matter of the code being wrong, but some methods seem to be not being called. In most of my trials it usually came down to the method Schedule. In my latest attempt, it came down to:

`new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();`

has been giving me the problem. The original error is

```
illegal start of type

invalid method declaration; return type required

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class delay
  location: class timer.TimerView.two

<identifier> expected

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class taskPerformer
  location: class timer.TimerView.two

<identifier> expected

';' expected
```

well delay is clearly defines as an Integer, but even after I replace delay with 1000 it tells me

```
illegal start of type

invalid method declaration; return type required

illegal start of type
```

So now I'm at a loss. I have look and looked, I've seen many success story's, but they almost never work with netbeans default bs. I can not import `java.util.timer` because from what I understand `javax.swing.timer` imports it itself or some nonsense.

I rarely ask for help but in hours of looking this up I have the exact same source code that i did 36 hours ago with a bunch of eraser burns. So I really hope someone can at the very least point me in the right direction. I've looked over Oricals tutorial, among others. that always leaves me in the same place. I've tried manipulating others programs that use the timer function, and I've even attempted to reverse-engineer the status bar that comes with a blank desktop application in netbeans. Just nothing seems to want to work., or more likely, my inexpiriance has me looking in the wrong places. The way I look at it this can't be that rare of a problem, but I cant get it to work.  Posted below is my program in its entirety, its not far from a blank netbeans app because of its simple nature. (all it has is a jLabel and the class I've been working on)

```
/*
 * TimerView.java
 */

package timer;

import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
import org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
import org.jdesktop.application.TaskMonitor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * The application's main frame.
 */
public class TimerView extends FrameView {

    public TimerView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);

        initComponents();

        // status bar initialization - message timeout, idle icon and busy animation, etc
        ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
        int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
        messageTimer = new Timer(messageTimeout, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                statusMessageLabel.setText("");
            }
        });
        messageTimer.setRepeats(false);
        int busyAnimationRate = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.busyAnimationRate");
        for (int i = 0; i < busyIcons.length; i++) {
            busyIcons[i] = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.busyIcons[" + i + "]");
        }
        busyIconTimer = new Timer(busyAnimationRate, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                busyIconIndex = (busyIconIndex + 1) % busyIcons.length;
                statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[busyIconIndex]);
            }
        });
        idleIcon = resourceMap.getIcon("StatusBar.idleIcon");
        statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
        progressBar.setVisible(false);

        // connecting action tasks to status bar via TaskMonitor
        TaskMonitor taskMonitor = new TaskMonitor(getApplication().getContext());
        taskMonitor.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
                if ("started".equals(propertyName)) {
                    if (!busyIconTimer.isRunning()) {
                        statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(busyIcons[0]);
                        busyIconIndex = 0;
                        busyIconTimer.start();
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisible(true);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                } else if ("done".equals(propertyName)) {
                    busyIconTimer.stop();
                    statusAnimationLabel.setIcon(idleIcon);
                    progressBar.setVisible(false);
                    progressBar.setValue(0);
                } else if ("message".equals(propertyName)) {
                    String text = (String)(evt.getNewValue());
                    statusMessageLabel.setText((text == null) ? "" : text);
                    messageTimer.restart();
                } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName)) {
                    int value = (Integer)(evt.getNewValue());
                    progressBar.setVisible(true);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressBar.setValue(value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Action
    public void showAboutBox() {
        if (aboutBox == null) {
            JFrame mainFrame = TimerApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
            aboutBox = new TimerAboutBox(mainFrame);
            aboutBox.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
        }
        TimerApp.getApplication().show(aboutBox);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        javax.swing.JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        javax.swing.JMenu helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        javax.swing.JMenuItem aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        statusPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        javax.swing.JSeparator statusPanelSeparator = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        statusMessageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        statusAnimationLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        progressBar = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

        mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N

        org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(timer.TimerApp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(TimerView.class);
        jLabel1.setText(resourceMap.getString("jLabel1.text")); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setName("jLabel1"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
        mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(178, 178, 178)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(188, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(133, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        menuBar.setName("menuBar"); // NOI18N

        fileMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("fileMenu.text")); // NOI18N
        fileMenu.setName("fileMenu"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(timer.TimerApp.class).getContext().getActionMap(TimerView.class, this);
        exitMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("quit")); // NOI18N
        exitMenuItem.setName("exitMenuItem"); // NOI18N
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        helpMenu.setText(resourceMap.getString("helpMenu.text")); // NOI18N
        helpMenu.setName("helpMenu"); // NOI18N

        aboutMenuItem.setAction(actionMap.get("showAboutBox")); // NOI18N
        aboutMenuItem.setName("aboutMenuItem"); // NOI18N
        helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        statusPanel.setName("statusPanel"); // NOI18N

        statusPanelSeparator.setName("statusPanelSeparator"); // NOI18N

        statusMessageLabel.setName("statusMessageLabel"); // NOI18N

        statusAnimationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
        statusAnimationLabel.setName("statusAnimationLabel"); // NOI18N

        progressBar.setName("progressBar"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout statusPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(statusPanel);
        statusPanel.setLayout(statusPanelLayout);
        statusPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 230, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        statusPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(statusPanelSeparator, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(statusPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(statusMessageLabel)
                    .addComponent(statusAnimationLabel)
                    .addComponent(progressBar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(3, 3, 3))
        );

        setComponent(mainPanel);
        setMenuBar(menuBar);
        setStatusBar(statusPanel);
    }// </editor-fold>




   public class two {



        int delay = 1000;
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

          int Number = 0;
          String Output;
          Number++;
          Output = Integer.toString(Number);
          jLabel1.setText(Output);
      }
  };
  new Timer(1000, taskPerformer).start();


   }







    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
    // End of variables declaration

    private final Timer messageTimer;
    private final Timer busyIconTimer;
    private final Icon idleIcon;
    private final Icon[] busyIcons = new Icon[15];
    private int busyIconIndex = 0;

    private JDialog aboutBox;
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

1) I'd sugget to use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `java.util.Timer`, because output from `javax.swing.Timer` is always in EDT

2) output from `java.util.Timer` to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater`, otherwise there no guaranted that anything should be diplayed/changed/repainted

3) for more informations you have to read [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

4) I'd suggest to create your code by hands, rather to use un-suppoted `Java Desktop Application` and layed by using `GroupLayout`,

Answer (score 0):

you start the time in the class like this way

```
public class two {
    new Timer(1000, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

as you can't write executable statement out of method this should be invoked from any method not from in class like this way you just declare the or define the object/variable you. this statement create new object but it will calling the start() method which was invalid statement try to call from any method like constructor or any other method